# How to set partition for X-axis and give label for that partitions in the chart with MPAndroidChart library by PhilJay?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I would like to set 4 partitions within one interval of X-Axis and give label for that partitions in the chart. Is there any way to set with MPAndroidChart library in Android? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXNJc.png)

Thank you!

[image: 4 partitions with labels in one interval]

Comment: I know, download sourceCode in BaseChartEntity,  initXAxis(.) method ,xAxis.setLabelCount(4) you can try it.

Comment: Sorry! BaseChartEntity means Chart and i can't find for initXAxis() method in there.

Comment: then you can see AxisBase.java, mLableCount default 6 ,you can change it 4.

Comment: The label count is for the whole bar. And i want to set 4 partitions within one interval.

Comment: you can invoke setLabelCount() method within one interval

Comment: Sorry for questioning again! How can i invoke for one interval?